# What's the purpose of a unit normal vector when creating a 3D shape?

Tags: graphics, mesh, java-3d

I understand that to create a shape (let's say a 3D sphere for an example) that I have to first find the vertex locations of the shape and second, use the parametric equation in order to create the x, y, z points of the triangle meshes. I am currently looking at a sample code to create shapes and it appears that after using the parametric equation in order to find the vectors of the triangle meshes, unit normals to the sphere at the vertices are found.

I understand why regular vectors in the first step are used to create the 3D shape and that a normal vector is perpendicular to the shape object, but I don't understand why the unit normal vectors at the vertices are used to create the shapes? What's the purpose of finding the normal of the vectors?

Comment: No expert here... but iirc the normals are used for determining how lighting against the object is rendered, and the formulas that accept the normal vectors are somewhat expecting them to be unit length?  I am under the impression that, for at least some calculations, the intensity of the 'reflection' or 'diffusion' of the lighting is directly related to the magnitude of the normal.  Also, IIRC, for a triangle, the normals from each vertex are summed then normalized (or at least divided by 3?).   Not 100% sure, but if they aren't unit length, I think some things might not turn out quite right.

Comment: Serge and mdunsmuir are right. Don't forget that the very latest version of Java3D (1.6.0 pre 11) uses JOGL which is a Java binding for the OpenGL and OpenGL ES API. If you don't normalize your normals, you can ask OpenGL to do so. At the end, OpenGL expects normals with unit length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I totally understand your question, but one very important use for normals in computer graphics is calculating reflections. For instance, if you're writing a simple raytracer, [Lambertian reflectance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance) is quite easy to compute if you know the normal vector where your camera ray intersects a surface. Normals are similarly required for (off the top of my head) the majority of calculations involved in more complex rendering techniques.

Comment: ... and indeed in less complicated rendering techniques: the surface normal is an integral part of calculating the lighting in pretty much every real-time algorithm since the Lambert model was first applied to flat-shaded polygons.